# Parse data from keyword based materials data file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, keyword

I have a keyword based materials data file. I want to parse data from this file and create variables and matrices to work on them in a Python script. The material file may have comment lines in the very top starting with the string "**", I simply want to ignore these and parse the data on other lines that follows a keyword of the form *keyword_1, and also their comma-delimited parameters of the form param_1=param1.

[image]

What is the fastest and easiest way to parse data from this kind of keyword based text file with Python? Can I use pandas for this and how?

below is a sample input material file: alloy_1.nam

```
*************************************************
**               ALLOY_1 MATERIAL DATA
*************************************************
*MATERIAL,NAME=ALLOY_1
*ELASTIC,TYPE=ISO
2.08E5,0.3,291.
2.04E5,0.3,422.
1.96E5,0.3,589.
1.85E5,0.3,755.
1.74E5,0.3,922.
1.61E5,0.3,1089.
1.52E5,0.3,1220.
*EXPANSION,TYPE=ISO,ZERO=293.
13.5E-6,291.
13.6E-6,422.
13.9E-6,589.
14.2E-6,755.
14.7E-6,922.
15.5E-6,1089.
16.4E-6,1200.
*DENSITY
7.92E-9
*CONDUCTIVITY
10.,273.
18.,873.
27.,1373.
*SPECIFIC HEAT
450.e6,273.
580.e6,873.
710.e6,1373.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way is to create a list of dictionaries where each element is a key = Category name and the data in the form of dataframe. We have to use a temporary dictionary to store the comma separated data which gets appended into the list of dictionary each time a new category is found.

Use the `pandas.Dataframe()` to create the dataframe

Below is the code:

```
with open('/Users/rpghosh/scikit_learn_data/test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# empty list of dataframes
lst_dfs = []

# empty dictionary to store each dataframe temporarily
d = {}
dfName = ''
PrevdfName = ''
createDF = False

for line in lines:
    
    if re.match('^\*{1}([A-Za-z0-9,=]{1,})\n$', line):
        variable = line.lstrip('*').rstrip().split(',')
        PrevdfName = dfName
        dfName = variable[0]

        createDF = False

        if (not createDF) and len(d) > 0:
            df = pd.DataFrame(d)
            # append a dictionary which has category and dataframe
            lst_dfs.append( { PrevdfName : df} )
            d = {}
            
        
    elif re.match('^[0-9]([0-9,]){1,}\n$',line):
        #dfName = PrevdfName
        data = line.rstrip().split(',')

        
        for i in range(len(data)):
        
            # customised column name 
            colName = 'col' + str(i+1)

            # if the colname is already present in the 
            # dictionary keys then append the element 
            # to existing key's list
            if colName in d.keys():
                d[colName].append( data[i])
            else:
                d[colName] = [data[i]]                
    else:
        createDF = False
        d={}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
lst_dfs.append({ dfName : df})
```

To view the output , you will have a list of dataframes , so the code will be -

```
for idx, df in enumerate(lst_dfs):
    print(f"{idx=}")
    print(df)
    print()
```

Output :

```
idx=0
{'elastic':   col1 col2 col3
0   21   22   23
1   11   12   13
2   31   32   33}

idx=1
{'expansion':   col1 col2 col3
0    4    5    6
1   41   15   16
2   42   25   26}

idx=2
{'density':     col1
0  12343}

idx=3
{'conductivity':   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0   54   55   56   51   55   56
1   42   55   56   51   55   56
2   54   55   56   51   55   56
3   42   55   56   51   55   56}
```

Comment: Thank you Rajarshi for the reply. However, I wasn't able to achieve my desired result which is to find a keyword and obtain the following lines in a variable until you hit the end of file or another keyword, in case of another keyword do the same while ignoring comment lines and white space lines.

Comment: ok clear about it now - let me chenge the code accordinly

Comment: @smoothy changed the code - it sud work now

Comment: Thank you @Rajarshi. I am able to have all keyword and data under them in the list of dataframes, lst_dfs = []. Now, however, I cannot succeed in assigning each keyword to a matrix. For instance, I would like to have ELASTIC in a matrix to work on them, plot them etc. Also, do we need col1, col2, etc, column names. I already know what each column is, for instance for ELASTIC, first column is modulus of elasticity, second is poisson's ratio, and the third is temperature. I want to plot, for instance, modulus of elasticity vs. temperature. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Yes - the name 'col-' can be avoided , if you have got the dataframe then you can use ```matplotlib.pylot.plot(df['1'], df['2']) ``` - I am too busy , could not work on your problem of scrapping

Comment: I used the dictionary key names within the for loop over enumerated list of dictionaries as follows, and it works fine: `if 'ELASTIC' in df.keys():
        elastic = df['ELASTIC'].to_numpy(dtype=float)`